# What is the primitive root of the following

Tags: elementary-number-theory

1. I happen to find some interesting questions relating primitive roots. 
   If $g^k$ is a primitive root modulo $p$ then so is $g$.
   I was thinking that we could say that $(g^k)^{(p-1)}=1\pmod p$ since $g^k$ primitive root $(g^{p-1})^k=1$ by Fermat ??
2. If $g$ is a primitive root modulo $n$ what is $g ^{\phi(n)/2}$ congruent modulo $n$?
3. If $g$ and $h$ are primitive roots modulo a prime $p$, what can one say about $gh$?

Answer (score 1):

- For the first question, if $g$ is a primitive root then $g^k$ is a primitive root if and only if $k$ and $\varphi(n)$ are coprime, Now if $g^k$ is a primitive root the $g$ is a primitive root (of course $k$ must be coprime to $\varphi(n))$. for the other part every element $a$ in $\Bbb Z_n^*$ verifies $a^{\varphi(n)}=1$.
- If $g$ is a primitive root the $(g^{\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}})^2=1$ hence $g^{\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}}$ is a root of order $2$ but we don't know which element is because there is a lot of elements of order $2$, But if $n$ is prime then we can prove that $g^{\frac{\varphi(n)}{2}}=-1$ .
- If $h$ and $g$ are primitive roots then $gh$ is not necessarily a primitive root, take for example $g$ as a primitive root and $g^{-1}$ is also a primitive root but $g\cdot g^{-1}=1$ which has order $0$

Note also that if $n$ has a primitive root then it has exactly  $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ of them.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, let us use a rather fundamental lemma.

We know that is $a$ has order k, then, $a^h$ has order $\frac{h}{(h,k)}$.

So, what does this tell us? Well, clearly, $a^k$ has already been shown to have order $\phi (p) = p-1$, so, we use the lemma, and another simple observation: The maximum possible order of any integer in a reduced residue set is $\phi (p)$.

So, we have that $\phi (p) = \frac{h}{(\phi (p), h)}$. This is where we find a contradiction if we allow that the GCD between $h$ and $\phi (p)$ be anything greater than one, we find that $a$ would have an order greater than the cardinality of the reduced residue set. Contradiction. Thus, it is also a primitive root.

For your second question, this one is an altered form of a familiar theorem. Namely, if $a^2 \equiv 1 \bmod p$, then $a \equiv \pm 1 \bmod p$. We now substitute that $a = g^{\phi (p)/2}$ and see that this is equal to $\pm 1$. However, we see that this must be $-1$, because if it were just 1, then g would NOT be a primitive root.

For your third question, this is rather general, but as already pointed out, this does not mean that their product is a primitive root. Not sure how detailed  of an answer is wanted there, though!

Comment: order of $a^h$ should be $k/(h,k)$ @Rellek